# I can not switch animations properly in unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, switching

I am making a jumping and idle animations in Unity 3d.
Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class JumpingD : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Animator anim;
    public float JumpSpeed_;
    private RigidBody _Character; //rigid body of the Character
    public Vector3 JumpVector;
    
    /*The thresh Hold level for the character to jump are
        1: Stay Idle
        25: Jump Up 
        */
    void Start () 
    {
        anim=GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetFloat("JumpSpeed", 1)
    }
    
    
    void Update () 
    {
        anim.SetFloat("JumpSpeed", 1)
       if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
       {
           _Character.AddForce(JumpVector*Time.deltaTime);
           anim.SetFloat("JumpSpeed", 25)
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is the jump animation don't play even after J key is pressed.
Always the idle animation plays
I want the jump animation to play after I pressed J key and after that the character goes idle again.

Comment: Don't use unity tag for questions related to Unity3d game engine. There's unity3d tag for that.

Answer (score 0):

On the first line of your update method, which gets called every frame, you set "JumpSpeed" to 1. It means that the next frame the player will stop pressing the J key, it will immediately drop to 1, so of course jump animation won't play "after" the player pressed J key.

Comment: Yeah I know that but I want that after Pressing J it plays the Jump animation and then when I Jump animation STOPS the J Button it plays the IDLE Animation again.

Comment: Thanks by the way golergka

Comment: Check how your animator is set up — that it plays animation fully before returning to the idle state.

Comment: How to actually set up like that? I don't know!